# Is it possible to access concurrently to the same DB from two different Servlets?

Tags: java, database, web-applications, servlets, concurrency

I'm developing a web application, based on a DB.
In my application, I access to this one from two different Servlets, and it's possible these accesses are concurrently.

I need to know if it is permitted, and if not, how can I do it?
Is there some trick to perform queries in a thread-safe way?

Comment: That's the whole purpose of a database server: to serve data to a lot of concurrent sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and how to handle will be database responsibility based on DB settings (isolation level settings).

Here are the isolation levels in [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and these may vary based on DB.

```
1.Read uncommitted (the lowest level where transactions are isolated only enough to ensure that physically corrupt data is not read)

2.Read committed (Database Engine default level)

3.Repeatable read

4.Serializable (the highest level, where transactions are completely isolated from one another)
```

Comment: Does this mean that it's possible to concurrently access a DB from two or more servlets? (I'm using a MySQL Server, with the default settings)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. As marko said, probably it is happening in your system right now because "Single Servlet" handles multiple requests, which means multiple calls to database from single servlet (assuming your servlet has database call code).

Answer (score 1):

One of the primary design requirements for databases is concurrent access. Fact is, you are most probably already doing it in any **one** of your servlets since they can serve several requests in parallel, usng multiple db connections. Using two connections from one app is (almost) exactly the same thing as using two connections from two apps.